# How do I fix the error about changing controlled input to uncontrolled in my code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, components

i have this div:

```
    <div>
      <MyHeroes>
        {myHeroesList.map((hero) => (
          <div key={uuid()} className="hero" onClick={handleName}>
            {hero}
            <div
              className="close"
              onClick={() => {
                handleRemoveHero(hero);
              }}
            >
              <CloseRoundedIcon />
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </MyHeroes>
    </div>
```

and I have this error popping up when the handleRemoveHero(hero) function is running. It's basically deleting documents from Firebase.

> Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be
> uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a
> defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a
> controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the
> component

Function itself:

```
 const handleRemoveHero = (hero) => {
    db.collection("swapi")
      .where("user", "==", user?.displayName)
      .where("liked", "==", hero)
      .get()
      .then((data) => {
        const id = data.docs[0].id;
        db.collection("swapi").doc(id).delete();
      });
  };
```

Comment: Is `myHeroesList` being updated via a firebase change listener?

Comment: yes it is updated in useEffect with setting setMyHeroesList with map

Comment: Could you please share that piece of code?

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    user &&
      db
        .collection("swapi")
        .where("user", "==", user?.displayName)
        .onSnapshot((s) => setMyHeroesList(s.docs.map((d) => d.data().liked)));
  }, [user]);

Comment: I don't see anything that would cause the error you're getting. Besides, you don't really have any input fields in this code. are you certain you're looking at the right lines of code? This error usually appears when you try to change the value of a textbox or input field outside the state.

Comment: https://swapi-738d0.web.app - if you login and then like any character, afterwards if you click on remove character it gives an error. There is search input field which sometimes is updated with setInput but this error comes out only when deleting character.

https://github.com/vadimberberian/swapi - code of project if you need

Comment: this may not fix your problem, but something I'm seeing: e.target.value and e.target.innerText can be undefined. Try setting a default value `const value = e.target.value || "";` at https://github.com/vadimberberian/swapi/blob/master/src/components/Search.js#L32 and  #L50.

Comment: setting both with this worked. thanks. i didn't know about this trick. I've tried defaultValue before and it didn't work but your solution worked perfectly

Comment: wait did the "uncontrolled input" error go away? Edit: either way, I clone your repo but can't reproduce the error.

Comment: yes it fixed the issue and i updated github instantly

Comment: that's a pleasant surprise lol

Comment: yeah the other issue i have is when i run handleName from Search component  <Suggestions>
            {suggestions.map((e) => (
              <p onClick={handleName} key={uuid()}>
                {e}
              </p>
            ))}
          </Suggestions> 
- everything works in safarin, but when running handleName from MyHeroes in safari it doesn't work. The for loop just won't start in Safari

Comment: sounds like a separate issue, feel free to open another question with more details :)

Answer (score 2):

For people with similar problems in the future:

This warning usually appears when the value of textboxes or inputs is changed outside of state or with a non-string value such as `undefined`.

Set a default value on input targets such as `const value = e.target.value || "";` or the destructured syntax: `const {target: {value = ""} = {}} = e;`